# Renaming files with its path name

Tags: rename, filenames

I have a .bdf file inside subfolders. All the .bdf have the same name: Loads.bdf

Example:

```
/home/user/folderxx/folderxxx/Load.bdf
/home/user/folderxx/folderxxx/Load.bdf
```

I need to find (and copy to a new folder) all Load.bdf files and rename them with its path name.

Example:
After the intended operation, it should show something like this.

```
folder001_folderAAA_Load.bdf
folder002_folderBBB_Load.bdf
```

Answer (score 11):

I would use the `mcp` tool from the `mmv` ("multiple move") package for that:

```
mcp '/home/user/*/*/Load.bdf' '#1_#2_Load.bdf'
```

The `#1`, `#2` etc. in the second string will be replaced by the contents of the corresponding 1st, 2nd etc. wildcard from the first string. Note that the path is in single quotes so that the wildcards are interpreted by `mcp`, not by the shell.

With the command shown, the files will be copied to the current directory. If you replace `mcp` with `mmv`, the files will be moved instead.

Comment: Double quoted strings also don't have wildcard expansion, at least in bash.

Comment: This was useful to me to copy the name of the folder to each file `mmv '*/*.m4a' '#1.m4a'`

Answer (score 5):

Using `prename` (aliased to `rename` on many systems) it is possible to do this without multiple runs of `mv` or `cp`:

```
cd /home/user
find . -type f -name 'Loads.bdf' -exec \
  prename -n 's:^./::; s:/:_:g; s:^:destination/:' {} +
```

Remove the `-n` when you are sure this is moving the files you want.

#### Update

To copy the files instead of moving them, the fastest way is to copy first with `cpio` or `pax`, then to rename as before. Eg (with GNU `cpio`):

```
cd /home/user
find . -type f -name 'Loads.bdf | cpio -p --make-directories destination

cd destination
find . -type f -name 'Loads.bdf' -exec  prename -n 's:^./::; s:/:_:g' {} +
```

Note that while `pax` is both POSIX and LSB and `cpio` is no longer POSIX, `cpio` is still the program which is commonly found many systems.

To handle filenames with newlines with GNU `find`/`cpio` it is possible to add `-print0` to `find` and `-0` to `cpio`.

#### Update 2

The `pax` solution is a one-liner (not including the `cd`):

```
cd /home/user
find . -name 'Loads.bdf' | cut -d/ -f 2- | pax -rws ':/:_:g' destination
```

Or for any filename (and GNU `find`):

```
find /home/user -name 'Loads.bdf' -printf '%P\0' | pax -0rws ':/:_:g' destination
```

Comment: There are [two renames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577767/get-the-perl-rename-utility-instead-of-the-built-in-rename), the perl one (aka `prename`, but called `rename` by default in Ubuntu at least), and the [other one](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) that doesn't use regex (known as `rename` on Arch and Red Hat). Also, `-execdir` is preferred to `-exec` (see `man find`). Finally, doesn't this command move the files, not copy them?

Comment: @Sparhawk, yes that's why I specified `prename`. Although I missed the 'copy` part in the question.

Comment: Ah okay (was that an edit?). Perhaps I just read it wrong.

Comment: @Sparhawk, no edit. Good call on the move vs copy though I have added an updated solution now.

Comment: I like this, but only my linux box has prename.  Not on the Mac, nor on Solaris.  Interesting tool, though, thanks for introducing it to me.

Comment: @Tim, updated with the `pax` solution, it has its own find/replace option.

Comment: Thanks, @Graeme.  Yet another interesting tool I was unfamiliar with. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to need to do this on a system that doesn't have the tools mentioned in some of the other answers (like mcp and mmv, or prename), and you want to do it entirely in the shell, you can do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

oldpath="/home/user"
newpath="/home/user/newfolder"

for file in $(find $oldpath -type f -name Load.bdf); do
        shortname=${file#$oldpath/}
        newname="$newpath/${shortname//\//_}"
        if [ -f $newname ]; then
                echo "$newname already exists."
        else
                echo "copy: $file"
                echo "  --> $newname"
                cp $file $newname
        fi
done
```

This script will find all the files named `Load.bdf` in the `oldpath` directory, munge the directory names into a new filename, and copy them to your destination directory.  We can also check for the existence of files already copied, in case you need to run it more than once, and we don't need to copy all the files again.

The resulting directory structure would end up looking like:

```
bash$ find . -type f
/home/user/folder001/folderAAA/Load.bdf
/home/user/folder002/folderBBB/Load.bdf
/home/user/folder003/folderCCC/Load.bdf
/home/user/newfolder/folder001_folderAAA_Load.bdf
/home/user/newfolder/folder002_folderBBB_Load.bdf
/home/user/newfolder/folder003_folderCCC_Load.bdf
```

Comment: thank you all for your information. i got lot more information than what i need. thank you again.

Comment: Awesome.. you could also outsource all the file existence logic to cp noclobber by dropping the whole if /else and using cp -n $file $newname

Answer (score 2):

In zsh, it's easy with [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv).

```
autoload -U zmv
cd /home/user
zmv '*/*/*' '${1//\//_}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
env - sh <<\SCRIPT

    t=/home/user/target f=folder
    cd "${t%/*}" && mkdir -p "$t"
    set -- $f??/$f???/Load.BDF
    while [ -e "$1" ] ; do
        cp "$1" "$t/$(IFS=/
            printf '%s_%s_%s\n' $1)"
    shift ; done

SCRIPT
```

I think this is all fully portable shell script - and it's pretty simply done, though I had my doubts at first.